# Why is F.prototype property inconsistent in logs

Tags: javascript, function, prototypal-inheritance, propertydescriptor

So Functions are of type Object and so can have properties. By default, function F will have a name, length and prototype property, and the prototype property will by default be set to an object which has one key "constructor" that points back to the function itself. i.e.

```
function F() {
  this.foo = "bar";
}

/* default prototype
F.prototype = { constructor: F};
*/
```

This can be proven by running `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(F.prototype));` which outputs

```
 {
    constructor: {
        value: [Function: F],
        writable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true
    }
 }
```

and that `F.prototype.constructor == F` evaluates to true.

What is confusing is that `console.log(F.prototype);` will output just an empty object `F {}`

Similarly `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(F));` will produce the following:

```
{
length: { value: 0, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: true },
  name: {
    value: 'F',
    writable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
  },
  prototype: {
    value: F {},
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false
  }
}
```

Why is it that these return an empty object `F {}` when i would have expected something like `{ constructor: [Function: F] }`?

Comment: because `enumerable: false`

Comment: `console.log(typeof F === 'function')`. Constructors make Objects when you call `new` on them.

Comment: Wow, I think you just pointed out that the makers of `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` don't understand that constructors are not Objects. Crazy.